# множественная функция "ЕСЛИ" в EXCEL

Tags: excel, функции

Каким образом воспользоваться функцией, чтобы в зависимости от величины значения в ячейке A1 в ячейке B1 выходило значение при условии, что "если а1<1000, то b1 =100, если  1001

Comment: Может вам нужна функция `ВПР`? Она выбирает из сортированой по ключу (от и до следующей записи) таблицы нужное значение.

Answer (score 2):

В зависимости от задачи и количества диапазонов можно использовать разные функции.

Для одного-трех вложений достаточно функции *ЕСЛИ*:

```
 =ЕСЛИ(A1<1000;100;101)
 =ЕСЛИ(A1>1000;1;ЕСЛИ(A1>700;2;3))
```

Первую формулу можно записать в таком виде:

```
=(A1>1000)+100
```

В Excel-2007 и более поздних разрешено вложение функций до 64-х, но при большом количестве условий такая формула будет громоздкой и плохочитаемой.
В этом случае удобнее иметь таблицу подстановок (таблицу соответствий).

В первом столбце такой таблицы пишем нижние граничные значения диапазонов, во втором - результат для таких диапазонов. 
Имея таблицу, можно вспользоваться функцией ВПР с поиском неточного соответствия:

```
=ВПР(что_ищем;таблица_соответствий;2;1)

=ВПР(что_ищем;таблица_соответствий;2)
```

Обе записи формулы корректны.

**Обязательно:**

а) в первой строке таблицы соответствий должен быть вписан 0, иначе значения, которые меньше меньшего в первом столбце, вызовут ошибку формулы #Н/Д;

б) значения в первом столбце должны располагаться по возрастанию.

Вот пример. Рисунок из другой темы, но принцип работы отображает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если диапазонов не очень много, их можно записать прямо в функции массивом констант. Для показанного на рисунке примера:

```
=ВПР(D2;{0;0,1:20;0,15:50;0,2:104;0,25};2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция условий такая:

```
=ЕСЛИ(условие;что делать если правда;что делать если ложь)
```

Таким образом ваше условие примет примерно такой вид:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A1<1000;100;ЕСЛИ(B1=100;50;ЕСЛИ(С1>20;23;24)));
```

Comment: нужно что-то вроде этого: =ЕСЛИ(F21<1000;100;100);ЕСЛИ(1001<F21<5000;200;200);ЕСЛИ(5001<F21<15000;400;400) и так далее но походу путаница со скобками

Comment: 1001<F21<5000 - правильно так: , И(F21>1001;F21<=5000).  Знак = применять там, где нужно, чтобы значение попадало в диапазон. С применением каскада ЕСЛИ обычно не требуется проверка двух условий в функции И, так как одно из условий  проверяется предыдущей или следующей функцией ЕСЛИ.